# Position <img> tags within a footer <div>

Tags: css, html

Having an issue moving these social icon images within the footer .  If I increase the height from 40px to 60px I can see the full image, but can't figure out how to move it within the section without changing the section size.

Code is below.  I'm stumped.  Thanks for the help. 
CSS:

```
.footer {
position:fixed;
/*Opacity start*/
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=80);
-moz-opacity: 0.80;
-khtml-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: 0.8;
/*Opacity end*/ 
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
height:40px;
width:100%;
background:#333333;
}

 div.socialIcons ul li 
{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
float: right;
}

div.footer a
    {
    color:#441111;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
div.footer ul
    {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    }
div.footer p 
{
text-align: center;
font-size: 75%;
padding-left: 10em;
padding-top: .5em;
color: #ECECEC;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer">


<!--   *****   Social media icons   *****   -->
<div class="socialIcons">

    <ul id="profile">
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/" title="Twitter"><img src="./design/twitter.jpg" alt="My Twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.pinterest.com/" title="Pinterest"><img src="./design/pinterest.jpg" alt="My Pinterest" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/" title="LinkedIn"><img src="./design/linkedin.jpg" alt="Me on LinkedIn" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p><i>&copy;2013</i></p?>
```

Comment: I can't see the problem, what size are the images? What should it look like?

Comment: Do you want to move the images horizontally or vertically? And how exactly do you want them?

Comment: Can you put this in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see the issue?

Comment: Images are 32x32.  here is a quick and dirty screenshot of what I'm seeing: https://twitter.com/phamousphil/status/391647330618703872/photo/1

Comment: I'm looking to move the images vertically up.

Comment: cant see that without signing up to twitter

Comment: remove margin/padding from the ul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "position: relative" with top/left/right/bottom to manually move a block without affecting other blocks.

Comment: don't you mean 'position:absolute'?

Comment: "position: relative;" and "bottom: 20px;" got me what I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Mood, no. Absolute cause block behaves like it's absent (so all will moves over). But relative doesn't affect near or parent blocks, so the  only relative positioned one moves.